# Bluebird equivalent of Q promise.post

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am currently migrating from Q to Bluebird.

I have the following to wrap calls to MongoDB:

```
DB.prototype.find = function(collectionName /*, query, projection, opt*/){
    if (arguments.length < 1) {
        return Promise.reject(new _Error("argumentsError", "DB:find expected collection name"));
    }

    var args = new Array(arguments.length);
    args[0] = 'findAsync';
    for (var i=1, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++) {
        args[i] = arguments[i];
    }

    var promise = this.getCollection(collectionName);
    return promise.call.apply(promise, args);
}
```

My problem is that with `Q` I could simply use `.post('findAsync', args)` instead of the `apply` on `promise.call`. Even if this code works, its a lot of LOC just for this.
Is there a better approach with bluebird ?

Comment: Did you mean Q's `.post(methodname, args)` method? The `.invoke(methodname, ...args)` method seems to be exactly equivalent to Bluebird `.call(…)`

Comment: Yes, this is `.call` but just `promisiftAll` your APIs instead with bluebird you don't have to resort to these methods.

Comment: @Bergi You're right thank you. I corrected the question. (It makes a lot more sense now)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I fixed the error in my question. This is not just about promisify'ing `mongodb`. The `.getCollection` method also controls if the DB is accessible (or not) and tries to fix the issues (if any) before returning the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if this code works, its a lot of LOC just for this.

I don't think the many LOC come from the `.apply()` statement. It's copying the arguments to the array that is so cumbersome, and in fact you'd had the exactly same 3 lines if you used Q's `.post()` method.

If you really care, you *can* shorten this to

```
DB.prototype.find = function(collectionName /*, query, projection, opt*/) {
    if (!arguments.length)
        return Promise.reject(new _Error("argumentsError", "DB:find expected collection name"));

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args[0] = 'findAsync';
    return Promise.prototype.call.apply(this.getCollection(collectionName), args);
}
```

(although this might have [performance implications](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments)). You might also want to try a simple

```
    arguments[0] = 'findAsync';
    return Promise.prototype.call.apply(this.getCollection(collectionName), arguments);
```

(assuming strict mode of course).

> Is there a better approach with bluebird?

I don't think so. Your code comment seems to suggest that you are expecting exactly three arguments anyway, you just might want to make them named parameters and pass them explictly to `.call()`.

If you are looking for a truly superior approach, head for ES6 with rest parameter and spread arguments:

```
DB.prototype.find = function(collectionName, ...args) {
    if (!arguments.length)
        return Promise.reject(new _Error("argumentsError", "DB:find expected collection name"));

    return this.getCollection(collectionName).call('findAsync', ...args);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. We are planning to switch to ES6 for the Node specific code but it's a big rewrite. For the moment I'll stick with the current code. I feel that the first solution -even if shorter- is a bit less pleasant to read (it kinda reads backward). The current method was written this way to avoid the arguments leak so I'll keep it this way.